# ReactNative FlatList scrollToIndex issue

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist, scrolltoindex

I have the following pieces of code in my App.js:

1. the `ref` for the main FlatList is set in a `useEffect` hook as `flatListRef`

```
const [flatListRef, setFlatListRef] = useState(null);
...
useEffect(() => {
    let mounted = true;
    if (refSlides?.current && mounted) setFlatListRef(refSlides.current);
    return () => mounted = false;
}, []);
```

2. the `renderItem` function that renders the desired component as an item of the FlatList

```
const renderItem = ({item, index, separators}) => {
    return (
        <View style={{
            flexGrow: 1,
            width,
            height
        }}>
            {
                item.component === 'Welcome' && <Welcome/>
                || item.component === 'Hospital' &&
                <Hospital
                    flatListRef={flatListRef}
                    history={navHistory}
                    slides={slides}
                    setSlides={setSlides}
                    slide={item}/>
                || item.component === 'Snippets' &&
                <Snippets
                    flatListRef={flatListRef}
                    history={navHistory}
                    slides={slides}
                    setSlides={setSlides}
                    slide={item}
                />
                || item.component === 'Disease' &&
                <Disease
                    flatListRef={flatListRef}
                    history={navHistory}
                    slides={slides}
                    setSlides={setSlides}
                    slide={item}
                />
            }
        </View>
    );
};
```

3. the actual FlatList definition

```
<FlatList
    data={slides}
    ref={refSlides}
    keyExtractor={item => item.key.toString()}
    renderItem={renderItem}
    getItemLayout={(data, index) => {
        return {
            length: width,
            offset: width * index,
            index
        };
    }}
    horizontal={true}
    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
    pagingEnabled={true}
/>
```

I have the following piece of code in any of my `Welcome`, `Hospital`, `Snippets`, `Disease` components. For example:

```
<TouchableOpacity
    activeOpacity={0.8}
    onPress={() => {
        setSlides([...slides, {
            key: uuidC.v4(),
            index: slides.length,
            uuid: item.uuid,
            component: 'Hospital'
        }]);
        flatListRef.scrollToIndex({index: slides.length - 1}); // <===== HERE IS THE PROBLEM
    }}>
    ...
</TouchableOpacity>
```

I have a main FlatList that has 2 components at the start, the `Welcome` component at index 0 and the `Hospital` component at index 1. In the `Hospital` component i have buttons, that when they are pressed, add another item (`Hospital`, `Disease`, `Snippets`) to the FlatList. The items are added successfully, i can manually slide to them.

The problem appears when i try to auto-scroll to the last item added. I want the following behaviour: after the button is pressed, a new item is added to the FlatList and auto-scrolls to it. Also i want to scroll at any index in the current FlatList.

The error i get is:
`scrollToIndex out of range: requested index 2 but maximum is 1`.

Why does it say that `maximum is 1` when i see with my eyes at least 3 items in the FlatList.

Have been at this for 2 days now, didn't find anything of use. Also i had not found examples where items where added or removed from FlatLists in conjunction with the scrollToIndex usage. Tried using VirtualizedLists, same problem as FlatList. I suspect it's a `ref` problem. I don't understand why the FlatList does not update the length of the data it renders, so i can scroll to it.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Is the height of each item the same?

Comment: Yes, the FlatList is horizontal, so each item has full height and full width.

Comment: Initialize `flatListRef` with `refSlides.current` instead of `null`.

Comment: @sandarshnaroju can't do that because at that point refSlides.current has no value.

Comment: `scrollToIndex`  should be called like this `flatListRef.current.scrollToIndex({
                    index: slides.length - 1
                  });`   and also, it is much safer to use ref to call scrollToIndex rather than a state.

Comment: @Bogdan May I ask how you are defining `refSlides` and where?

Comment: @sandarshnaroju i updated my post with `flatListRef.current.scrollToIndex({index: slides.length - 1})` because that's the way i was actually using it (still doesn't work). I define refSlides in App.js like `const refSlides = createRef()` and add it to the FlatList.

Comment: Define `refSlides` like this `const refSlides = useRef(null);` and then whenever u want to scroll use ` refSlides.current.scrollToIndex({index: slides.length - 1})`. createRef will give new Ref in each render, I think that is the problem. And also always use reference directly to call scrollToIndex rather than a state.

Comment: @sandarshnaroju ok, so i've done the changes you suggested. I passed the refSlides directly to my button, i used `refSlides.current.scrollToIndex({index: slides.length - 1})` on button press, i don't get the error anymore, BUT i am "scrolled" to the same window i press the button in. As you can see in my code, just before the scrollToIndex call i call `setSlides` to add a new slide. The `slides.length` used in the scrollToIndex call does not take the new slide into consideration.

Comment: @Bogdan  Ok `setState` take time to update its value, thats why `slides.length` is not updated after button press. How about you define another useRef which keeps track of slides data. Whenever you click button you update both ref and state with updated data. and in scrollToIndex use the slides data ref to scroll to the last item.

Comment: @sandarshnaroju can you provide an example? Thanks.

Comment: @Bogdan Initialise like this,
`const flatListRef = useRef(null);
 const slidesRef = useRef(null) //instead of null put the data of flatlist, I dont know where you are getting it maybe from api or as props, whatever it is put it here  
 const [slides, setSlides] = useState(slidesRef.current);`

for flatlist

`<FlatList
    data={slides}
    ref={flatListRef}
   {....}
/>`

Comment: @Bogdan and 
In your onPress fucntion 

`slidesRef.current =  [...slidesRef.current, {
            key: uuidC.v4(),
            index: slides.length,
            uuid: item.uuid,
            component: 'Hospital'
        }]; // here you have reference with updated flatlist data
    setSlides(slidesRef.current); 
    flatListRef.current.scrollToIndex({index: slidesRef.current.length - 1})`

Comment: @Bogdan Did you try it? Did it solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Update `flatListRef.scrollToIndex({index: I18nManager.isRTL ? array.length - index - 1 : index});`
Where index is from Flatlist renderItem